# Using Polymer CustomElements and HTMLImports polyfills together results in error

Tags: polymer

We've recently started using Polymer at work and we like it but we've found that the ShadowDOM polyfill causes serious performance issues in Firefox when used in combination with heavyweight DOM manipulation (we've encountered the issue with the DataTables jQuery plugin but the effect can also be seen by simply having Firebug open).

We can live without that polyfill so we decided to just use the CustomElements and HTMLImports ones. We followed the official guide on building individual polyfills and generated the minified JS files but when we use them both we consistently get this error:

```
"TypeError: CustomElements.parser is undefined"
```

When we use `platform.js` we do not get this error. I've even tried generating older versions of the polyfills to see if it is a recent issue to no avail.
When we dug into the code it seems the `bootstrap` function of CustomElements is calling `CustomElements.parser.parse()` - `parser` is added to `CustomElements` shortly before but between these two things something is resetting `CustomElements` and it loses its `parser`.

I've managed to replicate the problem in a small test case. I can't put it on JSFiddle as it requires HTML imports and I got CORS errors so I've had to host it on my shared server (please be gentle!). You will need to open it in Firefox to see the error (you also see the error in Chrome but it doesn't need the polyfill so the custom element still shows up):

http://lilchef.co.uk/polymer-polyfill-bug.html

By comparison here is the exact same test case but using platform.js instead. This works but includes the problematic ShadowDOM polyfill (if you open Firebug whilst running it you should experience the slowdown):

http://lilchef.co.uk/polymer-polyfill-platform.html

We should be able to use these two polyfills without having to use ShadowDOM shouldn't we? Has anyone else encountered this issue?